# RAII Failure - Why Does this C++ Code Leak? - throw in ctor in try block prevents dtor

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, error-handling, exception

The output of the program below is:

> begin try
>   Object() ctor
>   begin catch

Why is the Holder class's destructor not called?  Is this a memory leak?  Is it possible to call the Holder class's destructor without rethrowing?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>


class Object
{
public:
    Object() { std::cout << "Object() ctor" << std::endl; }
    ~Object() { std::cout << "~Object() dtor" << std::endl; }
};

class Holder
{

public:
    Holder() :myObjectP( new Object() )
    {
        throw std::exception();
    }
    ~Holder()
    {
        std::cout << "~Holder()" << std::endl;
        delete myObjectP;
    }
private:
    Object* myObjectP;

};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    try
    {
        std::cout << "begin try" << std::endl;
        Holder h;
    }
    catch ( ... )
    {
        std::cout << "begin catch" << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You might wanna take a look at [this](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/exceptions#selfcleaning-members), maybe it is enlightening

Comment: It's possible to wrap the entire constructor in a try/catch block, including the initialization list, but I've never done it and can't remember the syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, your `Holder` object `h` is not fully constructued, that is that `h`'s constructor had not finished its construction before the stack unwinding process had begun.

> C++11 15.2 Constructors and destructors
> (2)
>
> An object of any storage duration whose initialization or destruction
> is terminated by an exception will have destructors executed for all
> of its fully constructed subobjects (excluding the variant members of
> a union-like class), that is, for subobjects for which the principal
> constructor (12.6.2) has completed execution and the destructor has
> not yet begun execution.

Comment: Yes there is a memory leak. Unless you mean in the context of the program which will shortly end. But as far as the Holder class is concerned, there definitely is one.

Comment: Pretty sure your own answer says there will be a memory leak.