# Why does CLANG 3.5 on Linux cleans a "std::string" up twice when calling DTOR when throwing in CTOR?

Tags: c++, memory-management, memory-leaks, clang

There's a project focusing on using C++ 98 without additional dependencies, but it needs to maintain dynamically allocated memory. Smart pointers are not available, so code to manually clean things up has been added. The approach is to explicitly set variables to `NULL` in the CTOR, read some data during which memory might be allocated dynamically, catch any occurring exception and clean memory up as necessary by manually calling the DTOR. That needs to implement freeing memory anyway in case everything succeeded and has simply been enhanced by safeguards to check if memory has been allocated at all or not.

The following is the most relevant [available code](https://github.com/kaitai-io/ci_targets/blob/809259ebfffe1c754d9c514c751d93844ec6b6e0/compiled/cpp_stl_98/default_endian_expr_exception.cpp) for this question:

```
default_endian_expr_exception_t::doc_t::doc_t(kaitai::kstream* p__io, default_endian_expr_exception_t* p__parent, default_endian_expr_exception_t* p__root) : kaitai::kstruct(p__io) {
    m__parent = p__parent;
    m__root = p__root;
    m_main = 0;

    try {
        _read();
    } catch(...) {
        this->~doc_t();
        throw;
    }
}

void default_endian_expr_exception_t::doc_t::_read() {
    m_indicator = m__io->read_bytes(2);
    m_main = new main_obj_t(m__io, this, m__root);
}

default_endian_expr_exception_t::doc_t::~doc_t() {
    if (m_main) {
        delete m_main; m_main = 0;
    }
}
```

The most relevant part of the header is the following:

```
class doc_t : public kaitai::kstruct {
    public:
        doc_t(kaitai::kstream* p__io, default_endian_expr_exception_t* p__parent = 0, default_endian_expr_exception_t* p__root = 0);

    private:
        void _read();

    public:
        ~doc_t();

    private:
        std::string m_indicator;
        main_obj_t* m_main;
        default_endian_expr_exception_t* m__root;
        default_endian_expr_exception_t* m__parent;
    };
```

The code is tested in [three different environments](https://github.com/kaitai-io/kaitai_struct/issues/214#issuecomment-667555310), `clang3.5_linux`, `clang7.3_osx` and `msvc141_windows_x64`, to explicitly throw exceptions when reading data and if it leaks memory under those conditions. The problem is that this triggers `SIGABRT` on CLANG 3.5 for Linux only. The most interesting [stack frames](https://github.com/kaitai-io/ci_artifacts/blob/9cba84b5142d225efa8433acf2ee29fada2f5036/test_out/cpp_stl_98/valgrind.xml#L358) are the following:

```
<frame>
  <ip>0x577636E</ip>
  <obj>/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.19</obj>
  <fn>std::basic_string&lt;char, std::char_traits&lt;char&gt;, std::allocator&lt;char&gt; &gt;::~basic_string()</fn>
</frame>
<frame>
  <ip>0x5ECFB4</ip>
  <obj>/home/travis/build/kaitai-io/ci_targets/compiled/cpp_stl_98/bin/ks_tests</obj>
  <fn>default_endian_expr_exception_t::doc_t::doc_t(kaitai::kstream*, default_endian_expr_exception_t*, default_endian_expr_exception_t*)</fn>
  <dir>/home/travis/build/kaitai-io/ci_targets/tests/compiled/cpp_stl_98</dir>
  <file>default_endian_expr_exception.cpp</file>
  <line>51</line>
</frame>
```

[...]

```
<frame>
  <ip>0x577636E</ip>
  <obj>/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.19</obj>
  <fn>std::basic_string&lt;char, std::char_traits&lt;char&gt;, std::allocator&lt;char&gt; &gt;::~basic_string()</fn>
</frame>
<frame>
  <ip>0x5ED17E</ip>
  <obj>/home/travis/build/kaitai-io/ci_targets/compiled/cpp_stl_98/bin/ks_tests</obj>
  <fn>default_endian_expr_exception_t::doc_t::~doc_t()</fn>
  <dir>/home/travis/build/kaitai-io/ci_targets/tests/compiled/cpp_stl_98</dir>
  <file>default_endian_expr_exception.cpp</file>
  <line>62</line>
</frame>
```

The lines 51 one and 62 are the last lines of the CTOR and DTOR as provided above, so really the closing brackets. This looks like some added code by the compiler is simply trying to free the maintained `std::string` two times, once in the DTOR and an additional time in the CTOR, most likely only when throwing an exception.

### Is this analysis correct at all?

And if so, is this expected behvaiour of C++ in general or this concrete compiler only? I wonder because the other compilers don't `SIGABRT`, even though the code is the same for all. Does this mean that different compilers clean non-pointers like `std::string` up differently? How does one know how each compiler behaves?

Looking at what the [C++-standard says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35858302/2055163), I would have expected that the `std::string` being freed only by the CTOR because of the exception:

> C++11 15.2 Constructors and destructors (2)

> An object of any storage duration whose initialization or destruction is terminated by an exception will have destructors executed for all of its fully constructed subobjects (excluding the variant members of a union-like class), that is, for subobjects for which the principal constructor (12.6.2) has completed execution and the destructor has not yet begun execution.

The destruction is NOT terminated by an exception in this case, only the construction. But because the DTOR is a DTOR, it's designed to automatically clean things up as well? And if so, in general with all compilers or only this one?

### Is calling a DTOR manually reliable at all?

According to my research, calling a DTOR manually shouldn't be too bad. Is that a wrong expression and it's a big no-go because of the things I see right now? I had the impression that if a DTOR is called manually, it simply needs to be compatible to be called this way. Which the above should be from my understanding. It only fails because of aut-generated code by the compiler I wasn't aware of.

### How to fix this?

Instead of calling the DTOR manually and trigger the automatically generated code, one should simply use a custom `cleanUp`-function freeing memory and setting pointers to `NULL`? It should be safe to call that in the CTOR in case of an exception and always in the DTOR, correct? Or is there some way to keep calling the DTOR in a compatible way for all compilers?

Thanks!

Comment: You have `m_indicator` destroyed by the explicit destructor call `this->~doc_t()`, and then again when the constructor exits via exception. This exhibits undefined behavior by way of accessing an object after its lifetime has ended. The right way to fix it is to have all resources managed by RAII classes, and allow exceptions to propagate naturally. Even if smart pointers from the standard library are not available, you can implement your own; perhaps with fewer bells and whistles.

Comment: Your program behaviour is undefined since it uses identifiers with double underscores. Such identifiers are reserved for the implementation.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik But I would like to know why things only break for one compiler, if all compilers apply the same magic freeing at the same places of CTOR and DTOR in theory etc.

Comment: Undefined behavior is undefined. "Seems to work" is one possible manifestation of undefined behavior. Anyway, you can observe the actual behavior, by writing a simple class that prints something in its constructor and destructor, and otherwise does nothing; then add a member of this class to `doc_t`. I expect its destructor to be called twice when `doc_t` constructor throws.

Comment: [Here's a simple example](https://godbolt.org/z/YqMxq4) that demonstrates the behavior. Observe one constructor and two destructor calls. The previous link is for clang; [here's gcc](https://godbolt.org/z/KfrMae). Both behave the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simplified example that resembles your case, and makes the behavior obvious:

```
#include <iostream>

struct S {
    S() { std::cout << "S constructed\n";}
    ~S() { std::cout << "S destroyed\n";}
};

class Throws {
    S s;
public:
    Throws() {
        try {
            throw 42;
        } catch (int) {
            this->~Throws();
            throw;
        }
    }
};


int main() {
  try {
      Throws t;
  } catch (int) {}
}
```

Output:

```
S constructed
S destroyed
S destroyed
```

[Demo with clang](https://godbolt.org/z/YqMxq4), [demo with gcc](https://godbolt.org/z/KfrMae).

The example exhibits undefined behavior, by destroying the same `S` instance twice. Since the destructor doesn't do much, and in particular doesn't access `this`, the undefined behavior manifests itself by actually running the destructor twice successfully, so it can be easily observed in action.

---

Apparently, the OP has doubts that a destructor is supposed to actually destroy the object, together with all its members and base classes. To assuage those doubts, here's the relevant quote from the standard:

> **[class.dtor]/14** After executing the body of the destructor and destroying any objects with automatic storage duration allocated within the body, a destructor for class `X` calls the destructors for `X`’s direct non-variant non-static data members, the destructors for `X`’s non-virtual direct base classes and, if `X` is the most derived class (11.10.2), its destructor calls the destructors for `X`’s virtual base classes...

Comment: That example doesn't explain where the DTOR of `S` is called for which reason, but that's what I'm interested in to know. It seems to be called in the DTOR and in the CTOR in case of an exception only. But is that standardized for C++ in general somewhere or do compilers simply behave that way because it makes sense and do all of those behave the same way? I couldn't find anywhere explicitly stating that behaviour and the DTOR is obviously not called when the CTOR succeeds. So there needs to be some "magic".

Comment: You yourself, in your original question, provided quotes from the standard that require this behavior. I further demonstrated that two major compilers do in fact implement this required behavior. How they implement it is an internal implementation detail - the standard generally prescribes the observable behavior programs should have, not the means to achieve it. If you are curious about how, you can examine the generated assembly.

Comment: [A few more traces](https://godbolt.org/z/bsTbf6) demonstrate that `~Throws()` is only called once. `~S()` is called once from inside `~Throws()`, and again outside, when the stack is unwound after the constructor throws. Does this answer your questions?

Comment: What I quoted from the standard only explains why `~S` is called in the CTOR, because the exception terminates constructions, it doesn't explain why it's called from the DTOR as well. The quote explicitly mentions terminated construction or destruction and in this case the destruction is NOT terminated, but unrelated DTORs are called anyway. So do all DTORs contain that type of cleanup code for all compilers, because the standard requires that? Or is that an implementation detail and simply makes sense most of the time, because that's expected behaviour of a DTOR?

Comment: The point is that the DTOR cleans things up always in this example, while the CTOR only in case of the exception. The former is not what the quote says, because that only talks about terminated execution, which doesn't happen when calling the DTOR manually in this example. So there needs to be something else telling the compiler to always cleanup `S` in the DTOR or it's just the way it is because it makes sense most of the time or ...

Comment: It didn't occur to me that you would doubt that a desturctor is supposed to, well, destroy the object, together with its members. Anyhoo: "**[class.dtor]/14** After executing the body of the destructor and destroying any objects with automatic storage duration allocated within the body, a destructor for class `X` calls the destructors for `X`’s direct non-variant non-static data members, the destructors for `X`’s non-virtual direct base classes and, if `X` is the most derived class (11.10.2), its destructor calls the destructors for `X`’s virtual base classes..."

Comment: I wouldn't have been surprised if cleaning up data members would have been done conceptually outside the DTOR, so that calling that for itself would have been safe. Now I seem to know everything I wanted to know, so will accept your answer, even though I [summarized](https://github.com/kaitai-io/kaitai_struct/issues/214#issuecomment-668684251) it again for myself as well.

Answer (score 0):

Once the destructor is called, the object ceases to be (leaving you with uninitialized memory). This means that destructors may omit "finalizing" memory writes, such as setting a pointer to zero (the object ceases to be, so its value cannot ever be read). It also means that basically *any* further operation on that object is UB.

People assume some leeway on destroying `*this`, if the `this` pointer is not used in any way anymore. This is not the case in your example, as the destructor is called twice.

I am aware of exactly one case in which calling the destructor manually is correct and one where it is mostly-correct: When the object was created with placement new (in which case there will be no operation that automatically calls the destructor). The mostly-correct case is when destroying the object is immediately followed by re-initializing the object via a call to placement-new at the very same location.

As to your second question: Why do you want to explicitly call the destructor anyway? As far as I can see, your code should work just fine without all the contortions:

```
default_endian_expr_exception_t::doc_t::doc_t(kaitai::kstream* p__io, default_endian_expr_exception_t* p__parent, default_endian_expr_exception_t* p__root)
  : kaitai::kstruct(p__io), m__parent(p__parent), m__root(p__root), m_main() {
    _read();
}
```

The object is initialized to a valid state before the user-provided constructor is run. If `_read` throws an exception that should still be the case (otherwise fix `_read`!) and therefore the implicit destructor call should clean up everything nicely.

Comment: The DTOR is not called twice AFAIK, automatic cleanup happens in DTOR first and CTOR afterwards. When CTOR throws, DTOR is NOT called automatically. That's why I'm asking if freeing magic in DTOR and CTOR is common for all compilers, as it's only a problem in one tested. Besides that, the code is only an example of generated one and can't be changed too easily everywhere. The given implementation is the best compromise possible currently.

Comment: The dtor is called for each element that has been initialized at that point. Which means all members, as we are throwing after the element-wise initialization stage has taken place. Note that the initialization of the (super-)object is not yet complete, so it is not destroyed via its own dtor.